# Team Foundation Server 2013 Build Controller Fails With Service Activation Error 500

Tags: tfs, build

I have an install of `TFS 2013 Update 2 on Windows Server 2012 R2`.

I've also installed `TFS on a separate Windows 7 machine` to use as a build machine.

However, when I restart the build sevice on the build machine the controller and agents run for about 10 seconds and then display a red square. Under the 'Details...' link the message is

```
Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):HTTP code 500: ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException
```

I've tried all the suggested solutions for this (lack of available memory, multiple http headers, incorrectly configured web.config) and none seem applicable.

I have tried a couple of tests -

1. I restored the TFS databases onto the build machine and pointed the build service to one of the projects - the service worked fine.
2. I set up the build service on the existing Windows Server TFS install and I get the 500 error.

I have also reinstalled TFS 2013 from scratch on the Windows Server box to no avail. Has anyone else encountered something similar?

EDIT -

I've now found this error in the Application event log -

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/30405502
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/tfs/queue/Greenzone_2014/Services/v4.0/MessageQueueService2.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The extended protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the transport.  The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  IIS has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport has a value of Never.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The extended protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the transport.  The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  IIS has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport has a value of Never.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedAspNetEnvironment.ValidateHttpSettings(String virtualPath, Boolean isMetadataListener, Boolean usingDefaultSpnList, AuthenticationSchemes& bindingElementAuthenticationSchemes, ExtendedProtectionPolicy& extendedProtectionPolicy, String& realm)
```

EDIT I've found the solution -

Go to IIS Management Studio -> Authentiation -> Windows Authentication -> Advanced Settings

Turn 'Extended Protection' off

Comment: Not seen this one before... Are there any further errors in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: @RikRak - please see event log in original post